# Adding Pagination to Bigquery query in dataflowjob using pipeline

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am executing a Bigquery query in data flow using following code

```
p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery(getQuery()))
```

where 'p' is a pipeline Object.

When I am executing a query which returns large no of rows my data flow job is giving an error 'Resources exceeded during query execution.'

Is there a way through which I can add Pagination to my query?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my query to remove the order by clause and finally it worked for me